# Making entire cell active and inactive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am using UITableView with some cells & each cell contains buttons(3) labels(2) & UIScrollview.

Now when view loading all the cells are in inactive state. when i drag anything on to the table cell at that time only that particular cell has to activate.

How can we implement this.

Any one can help or suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method disable all the items in the cell and when didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method enable all the items for that cell.when deselect the cell disable or reload the specif cell again

Comment: @thats good.. Good to code..

Comment: hi i hav another question. i added UIView inside UIScrollView inside table cell. Here how can we get touches for UIView inside UIScrollView. Any suggestion for this.

Comment: First thing why you need scrollView inside the cell?? Because it is not a good practice to have several scrollViews inside the single view controller. table view already have a scrollview and again you put scroll in each cell creates a confusion to the user. And touchesbegan and touchesEnded method wont recognize well inside the scrollView. Its depend on what you want to show inside the scroll inside the cell. Better go with an invisible button inside the cell scrollView